# rEFInd bootloader doesn't launch on start

Tags: macos, partition, startup, unix, dual-boot

I installed rEFInd bootloader from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/), and run the install script. Everything seems to be successful. The install output is

```
ShimSource is none
Installing rEFInd on macOS....
Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil load -p /System/Library/Extensions/msdosfs.kext
Installing rEFInd to the partition mounted at /Volumes/ESP
Found rEFInd installation in /Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind; upgrading it.
Found suspected Linux partition(s); installing ext4fs driver.
Installing driver for ext4 (ext4_x64.efi)
Copied rEFInd binary files

Notice: Backed up existing icons directory as icons-backup.
Existing refind.conf file found; copying sample file as refind.conf-sample
to avoid overwriting your customizations.


Installation has completed successfully.

Unmounting install dir
Volume EFI on disk0s1 unmounted
```

However, when I hold option key while starting my mac, I am still getting the default apple bootloader. My SIP is disabled `"System Integrity Protection status: disabled."` and my T2 protection is also turned off. How would I be able to fix this problem?

Note: I am using 16 inch 2019 Macbook Pro and running MacOs Monterey 12.4. My final goal is to dual-boot Linux

Comment: Why wouldn't you just run a VM?

Comment: Because it is much slower

Comment: Since when?  What do you run under Linux?

Comment: Since always. I am running ros2

Comment: I love this. Someone asks a question, and someone else answers, "Why aren't you doing it totally differently?" as if the asker hasn't already been through 9 hellish consecutive days and nights of unproductive troubleshooting trying to get their way to work before giving up and starting over from scratch a different way. Nobody here needs to justify why they're asking a question, they need it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: The answer below assumes the EFI partition is installed on `disk0s1` with the name `EFI`. This is the default for Intel Macs. Also, the version of rEFInd downloaded is assumed to be 0.13.3.1.

On all Intel Mac models, the firmware (Mac Startup Manager) never checks for the installation of rEFInd when rEFInd is installed using the default settings. Therefore, the rEFInd installation is not displayed when holding the <kbd>option</kbd> key while starting the Mac.

Below are the reasons an icon for rEFInd is not displayed by the Mac Startup Manager. The file and folder exist in the volume labeled `EFI` in the EFI partition identified by `disk0s1`.

- The folder `EFI/refind` needs to be changed to `EFI/BOOT`.
- The file `refind_x64.efi` need to be renamed `bootx64.efi`.

One way to get rEFInd to appear in the Mac Startup Manager is to reinstall rEFInd by using the steps given below. The steps assume you are booted to macOS and have SIP enabled.

1. Remove the existing installation of rEFInd. You can use the commands below to accomplish this.

   ```
   diskutil unmount disk0s1
   sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
   cd /Volumes/EFI/EFI
   rm -rf refind tools
   cd ~
   diskutil unmount disk0s1
   ```
2. Install rEFInd using the `--usedefault` option. See webpage [REFIND-INSTALL](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/refind-install.html) for a `refind-install` man page.

   ```
   sudo ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.13.3.1/refind-install --usedefault /dev/disk0s1
   ```

   Below is sample output.

   > Note: The script uses the Linux version of the `sed` command, which is not compatible with macOS. Therefore, the script terminates early before the `bless` command is executed. Unless you have a very old Intel Mac, you can use the Mac Startup Manager to make rEFInd the default to boot at startup.

   ```
   ShimSource is none
   Installing rEFInd on macOS....
   Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil load -p /System/Library/Extensions/msdosfs.kext
   Installing rEFInd to the partition mounted at /tmp/refind_install
   Copied rEFInd binary files

   Copying sample configuration file as refind.conf; edit this file to configure
   rEFInd.

   sed: -I or -i may not be used with stdin

   Installation has completed successfully.

   Unmounting install dir
   Volume EFI on disk0s1 unmounted
   ```

---

I should point out that some Linux distributions install to automatically appear in the Mac Startup Manager. For example, this is true for Ubuntu. In such cases, the installation of rEFInd  is not required and may conflict with the `--usedefault /dev/disk0s1` option. When such a conflict occurs, you may avoid the conflict by adding an additional EFI partition for rEFInd.

Comment: Bad instructions. `-bash: cd: /Volumes/EFI/EFI: No such file or directory`

Comment: @JohnSmith: I posted a note at the start of my answer. If what is posted in the note is true, then there has to be a `/Volumes/EFI/EFI` or your Mac is really messed up. I state this because OS X/macOS stores files in `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/Apple`.